How to enable OMEMO encryption in openfire after installing inVerse?
How do I enable OMEMO encryption in OpenFire after installing inVerse?
I installed the inVerse plugin in OpenFire. But on the web page where I want to write a message and send it to the contact, the messages are not encrypted with the OMEMO protocol.
please guide me.

The Openfire inVerse plugin does not support OMEMO encryption, as the required libraries (libsignal-protocol.js) cannot be bundled with the plugin, due to licensing issues.
If you'd like to use the web client with OMEMO, you should install the webclient as a stand-alone application (instead of installing it as an Openfire plugin) and follow the instructions in the documentation of Converse.JS.
